# How to send a mail with special characters as subject by using sendmail command in unix shell script

Tags: shell, email, unix, csv

In my script i want to send a mail with some subject, some text as body along with csv file as attachement

My problem is subject has special characters in portuguese language
like this

```
Subject: Relatório de utilização do QRCODE
```

i am using sendmail command to send mail because i need to change sender name(not email id)

I tried this :

```
    Subject=Relatório de utilização do QRCODE
    mnth=$(date '+%m/%Y' --date="1 month ago")
    echo 'mês:'$mnth>>mailBody.html
    echo 'contagem de registros:'11090>>mailBody.html
    cat mailBody.html>out.mail
    echo "$mnth"
    uuencode QR_Log.csv QR_Report_$fname.csv >> out.mail
    sendmail -F "xyzname" "$subject" -f "receiver@abc.com" <out.mail
    echo "mail sent"
```

when i run the above script i am getting message like this :

> Syntax error in mailbox address "Relat??rio.de.utiliza????o.do.QRCODE"
>   (non-printable character)
>   mail sent

How can i achieve this please Help me...

Help is very much appreciated. I'll just wait

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a shell script like this and I got a valid title. Try to rewrite the code for sending mail like MIME:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'To: you@domain.net'>>test.html
echo 'From: Some User <user@domain.net>'>>test.html
echo 'Subject: Relatório de utilização do QRCODE'>>test.html
echo 'MIME-Version: 1.0'>>test.html
echo 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"'>>test.html
echo 'Content-Disposition: inline'>>test.html
echo ''>>test.html
echo '<span style="color:red;">Your message goes here</span>'>>test.html
sendmail -i -t < test.html
rm test.html
```

Let me know if this helped :)

Below is my old answer...

Not a linux guy but this may help you. First you must encode the subject to base64. For example:

```
echo 'your subject' | openssl base64
```

Let's say you've put the encoded string into $subject variable. Next you set the subject like this when sending email:

```
"=?UTF-8?B?$subject?="
```

Basically try to put **=?UTF-8?B?** before the base64-encoded subject and **?=** after it without spaces.

As I said I'm not too much of a linux guy but you'll manage :)

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: And one more thing, set charset to utf-8:
 echo 'charset="UTF-8"'>>mailBody.html

Comment: @ Veljko Manojlovic:Thanks your help but still i getting mail without subject after encode the subject

Comment: @user3531971 I edited the answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

rfc2045 -  (5)   (Soft Line Breaks) The Quoted-Printable encoding REQUIRES that encoded lines be no more than 76 characters long.
For bash shell script code:

```
#!/bin/bash
subject_encoder(){
  echo -n "$1" | xxd -ps -c3 |awk -Wposix 'BEGIN{
    BASE64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
    printf " =?UTF-8?B?"; bli=8
  }
  function encodeblock (strin){
    b1=sprintf("%d","0x" substr(strin,1,2))
    b2=sprintf("%d","0x" substr(strin,3,2))
    b3=sprintf("%d","0x" substr(strin,5,2))
    o=substr(BASE64,b1/4 + 1,1) substr(BASE64,(b1%4)*16 + b2/16 + 1,1)
    len=length(strin)
    if(len>1) o=o substr(BASE64,(b2%16)*4 + b3/64 + 1,1); else o=o"="
    if(len>2) o=o substr(BASE64,b3%64 +1 ,1); else o=o"="
    return o
  }{
    bs=encodeblock($0)
    bl=length(bs)
    if((bl+bli)>64){
      printf "?=\n =?UTF-8?B?"
      bli=bl
    }
    printf bs
    bli+=bl
  }END{
    printf "?=\n"
  }'
}
SUBJECT="Relatório de utilização"
SUBJECT=`subject_encoder "${SUBJECT}"`
echo '<html>test</html>'| mail -a "Subject:${SUBJECT}" -a "MIME-Version: 1.0" -a "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" you@domain.net
```